# Get NSException object from Exception breakpoint in XCode

Tags: objective-c, xcode, debugging

I am able to set an Exception breakpoint in XCode and the debugger stops when an exception is thrown. However, when the debugger stops there is no information about the exception (for instance the message or reason) just the stacktrace. I have tried using

```
register read
```

in the console, but that typically gives me information i am not insterested in. I have used a @try/@catch block however that requires modifying the code. Is there a way to access the NSException object when the Exception breakpoint stops?

Answer (score 0):

Click the run triangle a couple of times. Since the exception breaks immediately it has not had a chance to print out information about the exception.

[image]

File a bug: https://bugreport.apple.com.